# Inserting data into SQL Server database using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, registration

I am currently using HDI Membership provider and the design looks as shown below:

[image]

Now I am trying to create a new user and insert those values into the database as shown below:

```
Try
   Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HDIMembershipProvider;Integrated Security=True"
   Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
      cn.Open()
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@Username,@Password,@Email,@PasswordQuestion,@PasswordAnswer)"

      Dim param1 As New SqlParameter()
      param1.ParameterName = "@Username"
      param1.Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim()
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

      Dim param2 As New SqlParameter()
      param2.ParameterName = "@Password"
      param2.Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim()
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param2)

      Dim param3 As New SqlParameter()
      param3.ParameterName = "@Email"
      param3.Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim()
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param3)

      Dim param4 As New SqlParameter()
      param4.ParameterName = "@PasswordQuestion"
      param4.Value = txtSecurityQuestion.Text.Trim()
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param4)

      Dim param5 As New SqlParameter()
      param5.ParameterName = "@PasswordAnswer"
      param5.Value = txtSecurityAnswer.Text.Trim()
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param5)

      cmd.Connection = cn
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      cn.Close()
   End Using
   Successlbl.show
   Successlbl.show.Text = "Regisration Success."
Catch
   Errolbl.Show()
   Errolbl.Text = "Your account was not created.Please try again."
End Try
```

Now the problem is the data is not inserting to the database. I would like to know If anyone can point me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are swallowing any exceptions - you need to log the exception or at least find out what it is before any help can be given. Don't do a `Catch` without at least figuring out the exception.

Comment: @Oded-I'm getting this exception:Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert statement is incorrect - since you are not specifying any field names you should be supplying values for *all* columns.

The fix is to supply the names of the columns you are insert into.

The screenshot also shows that there is a required `ApplicationName` column, so unless it has a `DEFAULT` defined, you will need to supply that as well.

Assuming you have a `DEFAULT` defined on `ApplicationName`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users ( Username, Password, Email, PasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer) VALUES(@Username,@Password,@Email,@PasswordQuestion,@PasswordAnswer)"
```

Comment: @Oded-Now I have a problem that you only can solve this so now how do I mention the Application path as In web.config we have a membership tag within that we an mention Application name but in app.config how do I mention that?As I have asked now in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692694/how-to-add-application-name-to-appsettings.Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: @Kiran - First, off, I am **not** the only one that can help you. And it looks like you already got answers on it.