# How to add Application name to <appSettings/>?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, app-config

This is my app.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="Application Name" value="/MyApplication" />
    </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="frmStartup.My.MySettings.HDIMembershipProviderConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HDIMembershipProvider;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="HDIMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="HDIMembershipProvider" type="MyApplication.HDIMembershipProvider, MyApplication"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to use HDI membership provider and this is my Users table structure:

[image]

And in my recent question asked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5PZh.png) `Oded` helped me out trying to figure the problem with my Insert statement and I re-modified it and I have an ApplicationName column in my database structure I need to specify it.(As it should not be null value)

Now I need to add my application name by default to enter to database as we do it for web.config.

This is what I mean.

[image]

I need to add that MyApplication to my app.config file.

So How do I do that?

This is how I'm trying to enter user details to database but it is not enetering a single value

```
 Try
            Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=HDIMembershipProvider;Integrated Security=True"
            Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                cn.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users ( Username, Password, Email, PasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer) VALUES(@Username,@Password,@Email,@PasswordQuestion,@PasswordAnswer)"

                Dim param1 As New SqlParameter()
                param1.ParameterName = "@Username"
                param1.Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

                Dim param2 As New SqlParameter()
                param2.ParameterName = "@Password"
                param2.Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2)


                Dim param3 As New SqlParameter()
                param3.ParameterName = "@Email"
                param3.Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param3)

                Dim param4 As New SqlParameter()
                param4.ParameterName = "@PasswordQuestion"
                param4.Value = txtSecurityQuestion.Text.Trim()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param4)

                Dim param5 As New SqlParameter()
                param5.ParameterName = "@PasswordAnswer"
                param5.Value = txtSecurityAnswer.Text.Trim()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param5)

                cmd.Connection = cn
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()
            End Using
            Successlbl.show
            Successlbl.show.Text = "Regisration Success."
        Catch
            Errolbl.Show()
            Errolbl.Text = "Your account was not created.Please try again."
        End Try
```

Can anyone point me out where I'm making mistake.

And this is the final result I'm getting while entering to database:

[image]

To be more short and clear I need to enter the above shown User details to my database using the HDI membership provider.

Comment: @Downvoter-instead of putting -1 can you give some info so that I will try to improve my question so that you can understand it in a better way.

Comment: (didn't downvote) It's unclear what your actual problem is. Do you need to modify your app.config from inside your (winforms) app or when building or deploying your app?

Comment: When deployinng my application as when I am trying to create new user the values are not enteringto my database as recently I have asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692584/inserting-data-into-sqlserver-database-using-vb-net/8692611#8692611.So Now as mentioned the Application path to be entered manually as per my HDI membership provider I need to mention my application name in the app.config file.

Comment: Your question is bit vague. Please rephrase your post. Use <appSettings/> or  My.Settings.

Comment: @AVD-Sure I will repost it again with a clear view.

Comment: Now it's getting clearer: Basically you need an installer that will determine the application name and update the app.config accordingly.

Comment: @Filburt-I have reposted my question as while trying to enter the data I need to enter the application name along with the user details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem Myself after a lot of hair pulling and found the solution that I have changed my code in this way:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users ( Username,ApplicationName,Password, 
    Email, PasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer) VALUES(@Username,@ApplicationName,@Password,
    @Email,@PasswordQuestion,@PasswordAnswer)"
```

And add another Param this way:

```
 Dim param6 As New SqlParameter()
 param6.ParameterName = "@ApplicationName"
 param6.Value = txtApplicationName.Text.Trim()
 cmd.Parameters.Add(param6)
```

I know this not the best way If anyone found any other best solution let me know.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way by using the following steps:

1) Add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your application.

2) Add the following block to your app.config file, within the `configuration` section:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="/MyApplication" />
  </appSettings>
```

3) Retrieve the value and use it where needed with the following code (example from your answer shown):

```
param6.Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a AppSettings section to your web.config

```
<appSettings>

<add key="ApplicationName" value="/website1" />

</appSettings>
```

Comment: @user188308- have tried but not working though I have given the Application name as you mentioned.