# Create New User in Winforms Using HDI Membership Provider

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, custom-membershipprovider

I have a website with login and register forms using custom HDI Membership provider where Users can login or register new account.

Now I have a desktop software and trying to have two forms for login and register where my users can able to login or register for user convenience and not by going to the website and make them register online.

So, I have these to know in order to go further.

1) Can I use HDI membership provider as I have used it in my web application?
If so how can I do that?

As previously I have done and I faced many problems and still didn't get clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692694/how-to-add-application-name-to-appsettings)

2) If No, how do I make use in order to make use the same HDI Membership.

Finally I need to use the same database for my desktop software as well as my web application with all the possibilities (i.e. I need to validate each parameter of my membership class).

I am able to register the user but it is not using the Membership and I'm unable to know why it is not picking up the membership provider from the app.config file.

Once again I am providing my Users database Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you include information on where you obtained this membership provider (either from a site or homebuilt) and whether or not it is based on the standard MS membership provider structure?

Comment: This is from microsoft Asp.Net How do I videos?Here is the link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Comment: Ok, that is good news. You should be able to use the steps in my answer to solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *standard* membership provider in a Windows Forms application fairly easily.

However, without more details on the source of the HDI Membership provider, it will be difficult to provide exact instructions.

You can try the following instructions to see if they will work for you:

1) Add a reference to System.Web to your windows forms application.

2) Add an `Imports System.Web.Security` to the code file(s) where you want to use the provider.

3) Call the `Membership` methods as you do in the web, i.e. `Memebership.ValidateUser(user, password)`.

4) Add a `system.web` block to your Windows Forms app.config file (within the `configuration` section) and then copy the `membership` block from your web.config file to this block. For example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="HDIMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="HDIMembershipProvider" type="frmStartup.HDIMembershipProvider, frmStartup"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

5) You will probably need to add a reference to the assembly, project, or code that contains the HDI Membership Provider.

**Update**

Your app.config has two problems:

1) The appSettings section must be exactly as follows (your current appSettings has "Application Name" as the key while your code uses "ApplicationName"):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ApplicationName" value="/gAnnotation" />
</appSettings>
```

2) The membership section must be exactly as follows (the type must specify the fully qualified type name followed by the name of the assembly the type lives in and the defaultProvider must match the name in the added provider):

```
<membership defaultProvider="HDIMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="HDIMembershipProvider" type="frmStartup.HDIMembershipProvider, frmStartup"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

If you modify your app.config exactly as shown above, your application will work (I have tested it and verified that creating a user and logging in works).

Comment: @Competent_tech-I agree with you as this is the perfect answer and I have did the same thing as you said above with reference to my previous question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692694/how-to-add-application-name-to-appsettings/8692777#8692777 I am able to register and everything goes well but it is not taking the membership provider from app.config as I have an Application name which is set not null in the database structure but Without providing it It is not accepting any new user creation though I mention the application name in the app.config file.

Comment: As in my previous question I answered my own question If you can check that it will be easy to undestand what I mean to say.

Comment: I have provided a new answer to your previous question that shows how to set and retrieve the application name from the app.config. Can you edit your question to include your full app.config? I suspect there may be some issues there.

Comment: I am trying to edit and check if the code is working fine or not and will post my code.

Comment: I have updated my app.config file you can have a view at that and its still not working.

Comment: @Kiran: I don't see the app.config. Can you edit your question and add it? Also, can you provide a little more detail on what isn't working (error message; if so what?)

Comment: I have updated it my previous question as that dosen't relate here and  I am getting this error :The parameterized query '(@Username nvarchar(4),@ApplicationName nvarchar(4000),@Password' expects the parameter '@ApplicationName', which was not supplied.

Comment: You have added the appsettings key as "Application Name", not "ApplicationName" as in my answer to that question. So you either need to change the code that retrieves to reference the value in the config file or you need to change the config file.

Comment: I think I made a mistake can you modify it my code as it is difficult to follow and I am providing the entire source code with the membership provider so that you can have a look at my source and modify it.Here is the link https://rapidshare.com/files/2540659960/New.rar

Comment: Ok, your only issues were in app.config. I have updated the answer to show exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @competent_tech-Thanks a lot for providing the problem within my code and sorry to trouble you a lot.At last the day was ended with happiness..:)

Comment: you are welcome. Could you also mark my answer in the appSettings post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692694/how-to-add-application-name-to-appsettings) as the answer since this was part of the solution?