# implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

After I run the program, I add the data, and then i get this message:

> implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lGLxo1jXjg&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZxHuINmI3EIAjCq3zzsiFy&index=6) on YouTube and I did exactly the same as youtuber. It works for him but not me.

I am trying to add data from Visual studio into an SQL database:

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CONVERT(varbinary(max),'0xFFD8FFE000'))
Public Class Form1

Dim Conn As SqlConnection
Dim CMD As SqlCommand

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Conn = New SqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BYG-A101-MOELKA;Initial Catalog=App;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader

    Try

        Conn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into person (ID,firstname,lastname,age) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "')"

        CMD = New SqlCommand(Query, Conn)
        READER = CMD.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Datasaved")

        Conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Dispose()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: But what kind of data suits to be stored both as binary and character?

Comment: Schema of the `person` table?  And why are you using CMD.ExecuteReader()?  And please don't use string concatenation.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729200/executenonquery-for-insert

Comment: i only did what the youtuber did, in his case it works fine!!
I've created the table in such:
ID                       int primarykey
FirstName          Varchar (50)
LastName          Varchar (50)
Age                    int

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting data into SQL Server database using VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692584/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-vb-net)

Comment: Blam: I appreciate that you are trying to find a solution for me. However, i'm still learning and i haven't gotten into parameters yet. Therefore, it's hard for me to reflect from the link you've send me. 
As I said before, the programmer on youtube made it work and i cannot understand why it's not working for me. it keeps saying that i should use the CONVERT function!! so what i'm i missing?
Should i change the whole code or should i insert/delete 1 or 2 to make it work?

Comment: So.... is this thread dead? should i make another?

Answer (score 1):

A few problems

ExecuteReader should not be used for an insert
use [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

That is subject to injection attack.  Use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx).  The parameters must match the data type of the table columns.

Comment: I've tried to read a lot about parameters... but i can't seem to understand how to make one with my code.
Also, as i said, i'm trying to learn how from a youtuber (I've posted the link) In his case, it works fine. Can you please demonstrate it for me. i'm stuck

Comment: Start with ExecuteReader should not be used for an insert

Comment: Ok, that i did, i removed ( READER = CMD.ExecuteReader) and replaced it with (CMD.ExecuteNonQuery)
Same problem