# "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query." error

Tags: implicit-conversion, varbinary

When I try to execute the following query using Hibernate, I am facing the following error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

```
String sql = "select distinct t.titleNo  from Ties t ,Titles se,TieType TT ,Net NTT "  
                        +" where t.seriesNo  = se.titleNo and t.titleType=TT.titleType and TT.titleTypeNo = NTT.titleTypeNo  "
                        +" and  ((((t.titleName LIKE '%'+:titleName+'%')  OR (:titleName LIKE '%'+ t.titleName+'%')) AND (ISNULL(TT.titleBaseType,'') ='')  "
                        +" And Isnull(:titleBaseType,'') <> 'N')  "     
                        +"   OR (((t.titleName LIKE :titleName)  OR (:titleName LIKE t.titleName)) AND (ISNULL(TT.titleBaseType,'') ='N')))   "
                        +"   AND (IsNull(se.titleName,'%') like CASE WHEN (:seriesNo>0) THEN  (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(:seriesName),1,6)+'%') ELSE '%' END)";

                Query qry = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                qry.setParameter("titleName", titleName); //String
                qry.setParameter("seriesNo", seriesNo); //Integer
                qry.setParameter("titleBaseType", titleBaseType); //String
                qry.setParameter("seriesName", seriesName); //String
qry.list();
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293748/implicit-conversion-from-data-type-varchar-to-varbinary-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you datatype is not matching with the datatype of database columns. Check the datatypes properly. you can find mapping [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types)